# Solution to the problem of John Nash's class in 1950 and the Alicia's solution

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, homology-cohomology

1. In John Nash's class shown in [A Beautiful Mind (5/11) Movie CLIP - Alicia's Solution (2001)](https://youtu.be/pYdjNeFh6zw), what precisely is the problem and what exactly is the solution?

It looks to me that the $V$ is the solution of vector space $\mathbf{R}^3$ with vector field $F$ such that the $$ d \vec F =0,$$
while the $W$ is the solution of vector space $\mathbf{R}^3$ with vector field $F$ such that the $$  \vec F =d g.$$

Then the
$
V/W
$
is the quotient (kernel mod image) of the set such that $d \vec F =0,$ but $\vec F \neq d g$.

Then the
$$
\dim(V/W) =?
$$

2. In Alicia's solution presented [here](https://youtu.be/prELTZi6uks?t=67), it was said that she assumed the vector field is a rational function $$  \vec F \in \mathbf{Q}.$$
   What is her solution? Why incorrect? and what will be the correction to her solution?

(p.s. John Nash said: "Your solution is elegant, but on this particular occasion, ultimately incorrect.")

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would say de Rham cohomology, closed/exact

Comment: Thanks for the ref, but that question does not have an official answer yet. So I would be happy to hear the clear question and answer.

Comment: Also did he write dim(/)=? or dim(/)=8?

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS It doesn't have an *accepted* answer, but being accepted doesn't make an answer "official". The linked question has a highly upvoted answer which (in my opinion) addresses your question quite thoroughly.

Comment: I added a new part 2 question on Alicia's solution.